# Vagrant to test chef recipies - but how to deal with private git

Tags: git, github, chef-infra, vagrant

I use vagrant to test my chef recipes.  The issue is that I have clone my private repo and the machine is not auteticated.  How can i automated git authentication to boostrap chef?  I am using the vagrant ubuntu 11.10 with chef.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to provision with chef-solo, chef-server, or something else? For reference [see these docs](http://vagrantup.com/v1/docs/provisioners.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[use ssh keys with passphrase on a vagrant+chef setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211287/use-ssh-keys-with-passphrase-on-a-vagrantchef-setup)
will have similar answers that might be helpful.

Without knowing more details of chef-solo, or chef-client + chef-server. It comes down to ssh keys.

Make sure you are authing with something like
`git@github.com:user/repo.git`

Then you will want to ensure that your VM and underlying host is ssh agent forwarding.

Make sure your ~/.ssh/config has the appropriate line. A general example is.

```
host *
    ForwardAgent yes
```

Remember that first match wins in ~/.ssh/config , not the most specific

Then you may have to add any identities with `ssh-add` and make sure `ssh-agent` is there as well.

Finally, in the Vagrantfile,
`config.ssh.forward_agent = true`

Comment: Great answer. However, please don't use 'host *' instead specify an IP or a domain lke "host example.com". https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-agent-forwarding