# How to setup Vagrant ssh agent forwarding?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, chef-infra, vagrant

My goal is to connect from a VirtualBox VM to another machine using the ssh key authentication. I have created the VM with Vagrant (1.0.5). I have also enabled config.ssh.forward_agent = true (as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955525/how-to-use-ssh-agent-forwarding-with-vagrant-ssh)). Sadly, the ssh forwarding does not seem to be working.

These are the steps (on fresh ubuntu with vagrant and virtualbox):

1. Log from the host machine to VM (when I use --debug, I see that the forwarding is enabled)

   > vagrant ssh
2. Log from VM (ubuntu 12.04 with injected vagrant ssh key) to external machine

   > ```
   > ssh -A sk@192.168.0.1
   > ```

   to get: Permission denied.

Do I need to perform any additional step to make it work? People advice to use ssh-add -K. It is not clear for me on which machine.

Comment: Make sure you're not using a ssh-agent within your VM

Comment: Thx for the suggestion. I have found also this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699333/vagrant-to-test-chef-recipies-but-how-to-deal-with-private-git?rq=1. It suggests to modify .ssh/config. I will check my VM tomorrow when I get to the office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not make the ssh forwarding working. My solution is to simply generate new ssh key on the VM:

1. Log to the VM: *vagrant ssh*
2. Generate a new ssh key on the VM: *ssh-keygen*
3. Upload the new public ssh to 192.168.0.1: I do it manually. It could be automatize.
4. *ssh -A sk@192.168.168.0.1* works