# Ansible 1.6 + Vagrant 1.6 ssh forwarding doesn't look like it's working

Tags: git, ssh, vagrant, provisioning, ansible

Provisioning with a git task on vagrant + ansible doesn't appear to be working, guessing the problem is ssh-forwarding.

If I ssh into the box, I can `git clone` just fine. I can look with `ssh-add -L` and see my key has indeed been forwarded.

When I run `vagrant provision` though, I get:

```
failed: [ss_app] => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/git ls-remote git@github.com:org/app.git -h refs/heads/master", "failed": true, "item": "", "rc": 128}
stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

On the task:

```
- name: install from git
  git: >
    repo={{ app.repo }} 
    dest={{ app.home }} 
    version={{ app.version }} 
    accept_hostkey=yes
    update=yes
```

With this in my `ansible.cfg`:

```
[defaults]
transport = ssh

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ForwardAgent=yes -A
```

I've also tried using:

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "provision.yml"
    ansible.inventory_path = "hosts/vagrant"
    ansible.sudo = true
    ansible.host_key_checking = false
    ansible.verbose =  'vvvv'
    ansible.extra_vars = { 
                           ansible_ssh_user: 'vagrant', 
                           ansible_connection: 'ssh',
                           ansible_ssh_args: '-o ForwardAgent=yes'
                         }
end
```

Per some other stack overflow questions. None of these work, though.

Thoughts?

---

Edit:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "provision.yml"
    ansible.inventory_path = "hosts/vagrant"
    ansible.sudo = true
    ansible.host_key_checking = false
    ansible.verbose =  'vvvv'
    ansible.extra_vars = { 
                           ansible_ssh_user: 'vagrant', 
                           ansible_connection: 'ssh',
                           ansible_ssh_args: '-o ForwardAgent=yes -A'
                         }
    # ansible.limit = 'all'
  end

  config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  config.vm.define :ss_app do |ss_app_config|
    ss_app_config.vm.box = "precise64"
    ss_app_config.vm.box_url = "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/precise/current/precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box"

    ss_app_config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.1.100.100"
    ss_app_config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 2222, id: 'ssh', auto_correct: true

    ss_app_config.ssh.forward_agent = true

    ss_app_config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |virtualbox|
      virtualbox.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
    end
  end
end
```

^^ There's more of my Vagrantfile.

And here's the command being run: `/usr/bin/git ls-remote git@github.com:org/app.git -h refs/heads/master`

If I login via `vagrant ssh` then run that command, it works fine, only fails during the provision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue myself just the past few days. The solutions you have tried are overly-complicated as some of them were for earlier versions of Vagrant and Ansible.

Here is something simpler and cleaner:

1. Set `sudo: no` to the *"install from git"* task. (For sudo by default, You can leave `ansible.sudo = true` in Vagrantfile or do `sudo: yes` at the play for other tasks)
2. Make sure `ss_app_config.ssh.forward_agent = true` is there
3. Remove from your Vagrantfile, `ansible.host_key_checking`, `ansible.extra_vars` as they are not required for ssh agent forwarding.
4. Remove `ansible.cfg` file, not needed

Hopefully, it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

My solution to a similar issue was to make SSH agent-forward works with sudo with the following ansible tasks:

```
- name: Copy sudoers file for safety
  command: cp -f /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.tmp

- name: Create sudoers file backup
  command: cp -f /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.bak

- name: Create admins group
  group: name=admins system=yes state=present

- name: make sure we can sudo as admin group
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/sudoers.tmp state=present regexp='^%admin' line='%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL'

- name: Make sure ssh-agent works via sudo
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/sudoers.tmp state=present regexp='^Defaults env_keep\+\=SSH_AUTH_SOCK' line='Defaults env_keep+=SSH_AUTH_SOCK'

- name: Final sudoers file check
  shell: visudo -q -c -f /etc/sudoers.tmp && cp -f /etc/sudoers.tmp /etc/sudoers
```

Answer (score 1):

You can (should) enable [SSH-Forwarding via Vagrant settings](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html):

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "..."

  config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
    ansible.verbose = 'v'
  end

end
```

Note that as of Vagrant 1.6.0 (with ansible.verbose enabled), the [ansible-playbook command used by Vagrant is showed](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/3628) (useful for debugging).

If you still have problem, could you please provide a Vagrantfile example and the ansible-playbook command generated by your `vagrant provision` run?

Comment: Hum, I already had that in there. I edited my post with the requested info.

Comment: In order to better understand where the problem is, could you please manually execute in a shell the ansible-playbook command generated by vagrant (including environment variables), something like: `ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=true ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=true PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS='-o ForwardAgent=yes -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s' ansible-playbook --private-key=...` (with -vvvv log verbosity)

Comment: As it seems that you use `ansible.sudo = true`, the git ansible task will be executed by 'root' user, and not 'vagrant' remote/ssh user. See similar Ansible issues: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/6443 and https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/6499

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/a/22768453/2951970 `sudo: no` is used on the git task to avoid this problem. I would suggest that you rename your question as something like: "How to apply ssh-forwarding to ansible tasks that use sudo option?" The solution from @sebastibe is quite interesting, but in the case of `git` I think that sudo is most of the time unnecessary/unwanted.

Comment: For the records, see also GitHub FAQ about [Error: Permission denied (publickey)](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey). In general, _You should not be using the sudo command with Git_.

Comment: Thanks for all the information, I've been working with Vagrant + Ansible for about a week now, definitely didn't fully realize it was being run as root, obviously I see why, just still grasping everything. All this has been uber helpful, cheers!