# Chef, Vagrant and private git cloning

Tags: ruby, git, vagrant, chef-infra, host

i have acces to git repo on host, and i have a Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu14.04"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-    vagrant-disk1.box"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = 1024
    vb.cpus = 2
  end
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  # chef.log_level = :debug
    chef.cookbooks_path = "./cookbooks"
    chef.add_recipe "git_sync"
  end
end
```

if i run vagrant and ssh into it, i could also git clone my private repo, (recipe "install_pkgs" is to install git on vm) but the pecipe "git_sync" gets an error like:

```
[2015-05-08T18:40:26+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2015-05-08T18:40:26+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2015-05-08T18:40:26+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2015-05-08T18:40:26+00:00] ERROR: git[/home/vagrant/geomongo] (git_sync::default line 1) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '128'
---- Begin output of git ls-remote "git@bitbucket.org:galiaf95/test.git" HEAD ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
---- End output of git ls-remote "git@bitbucket.org:galiaf95/test.git" HEAD ----
Ran git ls-remote "git@bitbucket.org:galiaf95/test.git" HEAD returned 128

================================================================================
Error executing action `sync` on resource 'git[/home/vagrant/geomongo]'
================================================================================


Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '128'
---- Begin output of git ls-remote "git@bitbucket.org:galiaf95/test.git" HEAD ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
---- End output of git ls-remote "git@bitbucket.org:galiaf95/test.git" HEAD ----
Ran git ls-remote "git@bitbucket.org:galiaf95/test.git" HEAD returned 128


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/git_sync/recipes/default.rb

  1: git "/home/vagrant/geomongo" do
  2:   # repository "git@bitbucket.org:osll/geomongo.git"  
  3:   # repository "https://github.com/galiaf95/test.git"
  4:   repository "git@bitbucket.org:galiaf95/test.git"
  5:   action :sync
  6: end


Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/git_sync/recipes/default.rb:1:in `from_file'

git("/home/vagrant/geomongo") do
  provider Chef::Provider::Git
  action [:sync]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  destination "/home/vagrant/geomongo"
  revision "HEAD"
  remote "origin"
  cookbook_name :git_sync
  recipe_name "default"
  repository "git@bitbucket.org:galiaf95/test.git"
end



[2015-05-08T18:38:31+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
[2015-05-08T18:40:26+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

Here is my git_sync.rb recipe

```
git "/home/vagrant/geomongo" do"
  repository "git@bitbucket.org:galiaf95/test.git"
  action :sync
end
```

I'm new to chef and vagrant and it would be great to have some very comprehensive examples of how to clone private repo using chef.

Problem solved with this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/8191279/3564452 But can someone, please, discribe what's going on in this recipe and how this fixes my problem.

Comment: One of the first things you need to do before running any `git` commands is deploy an SSH key that's authorized on your git service, Bitbucket in this case. Until that's done, it won't be able to authenticate.

Comment: I've already done that. But this didn't fix my problem.

Comment: You need to make sure they have the correct permissions set (0700 mode, for example) or SSH will ignore them. Try to ssh into the machine and execute the `git clone` command manually to test.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm no chef expert, but I have a similar setup working with Salt...)

The issue is that when you log on, you set up the ssh known_host as the user "vagrant", and the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable is set for that user too. When you run your Chef recipes in the provisioner, they run as root. So, you need to add your host to the /root/.ssh/known_hosts and also you need to edit /etc/sudoers to allow SSH_AUTH_SOCK to be passed through, something like so, although you'll obviously need to port my `salt-call` line to Chef.

```
config.vm.provision "setup-and-highstate", type: "shell" do |s|
    s.inline = <<SCRIPT
    grep -s SSH_AUTH_SOCK /etc/sudoers || echo 'Defaults        env_keep="SSH_AUTH_SOCK"' | (EDITOR="tee -a" visudo)
    ln -s /var/cache/salt/minion/extmods/outputters/ /var/cache/salt/minion/extmods/output
    salt-call --local 'ssh.set_known_host' 'root' enc='ecdsa' fingerprint='ff:ff:ff:23:b4:20:93:d1:2e:91:ff:3c:a8:ff' hostname='git.xxxx.yyyy.com'
SCRIPT
end
```

Answer (score 0):

With the error string `Host key verification failed.` to me it sounds like one of three things:

1. you didn't add your SSH keys to your BitBucket repository
2. the SSH key on your node is formatted incorrectly (a trailing space or newline for instance)
3. you didn't `ssh-add` your SSH key on your node

In regards to the HOSTS issue, you can use the [`ssh_known_hosts` cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/ssh_known_hosts) resource to add the `git@bitbucket.org` address prior to using the `git` resource.